# Is there a way to find all children of a Matlab class?

Tags: matlab, oop, subclass, class-hierarchy

The Matlab function [`superclasses`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/superclasses.html?searchHighlight=superclasses) returns the names of all parents of a given class.

Is there an equivalent to find all classes *derived* from a given class, *i.e.* children classes ? The function [`allchild`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/allchild.html?searchHighlight=allchild) seems to be restricted to graphical handles.

If not, what strategy could be adopted to get such a list ? Is brute force path scanning the only option ?

Let's restrict ourselves to the classes in Matlab's path.

Comment: I am just wondering what you want to use this for?

Comment: @Bernhard I'm building a documentation engine for custom programs. I find it would be very useful to have, on a class page, a list of both the parents and children classes.

Comment: Did you look for existing solutions first? If I am searching for doxygen and matlab, I find quite some solutions that may work. Do those not work for you.

Comment: @Ratbert - Is there anything unsatisfactory about my answer...?

Comment: @Ratbert yeah it would be nice to receive some feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. They are very complete and it takes time to test and understand the details. At the end of the day, the answer is essentially what I was afraid of: brute force path scanning is the only strategy ...

Answer (score 7):

> ### Intro:
>
> During the course of the solution I seem to have found an undocumented static method of the `meta.class` class which returns all cached classes (pretty much everything that gets erased when somebody calls `clear classes`) and also (entirely by accident) made a tool that checks `classdef` files for errors.

---

Since we want to find ***all*** subclasses, the sure way to go is by making a list of ***all known*** classes and then checking for each one if it's derived from any other one. To achieve this we separate our effort into 2 types of classes:

- "*Bulk classes*" - here we employ the [`what`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/what.html) function to make a list of files that are just "laying around" on the MATLAB path, which outputs a structure `s` (described in the docs of [`what`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/what.html#zmw57dd0e913453) having the following fields: `'path' 'm' 'mlapp' 'mat' 'mex' 'mdl' 'slx' 'p' 'classes' 'packages'`. We will then select some of them to build a list of classes. To identify what kind of contents an .m or a .p file has (what *we* care about is class/not-class), we use [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html). [This method is demonstrated by Loren in her blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/08/26/what-kind-of-matlab-file-is-this/). In my code, this is `mb_list`.
- "*Package classes*" - this includes class files that are indexed by MATLAB as part of its internal package structure. The algorithm involved in getting this list involves calling [`meta.package.getAllPackages`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.package.getallpackages.html) and then recursively traversing this top-level package list to get all sub-packages. Then a class list is extracted from each package, and all lists are concatenated into one long list - `mp_list`.

The script has two input flags (`includeBulkFiles`,`includePackages`) that determine whether each type of classes should be included in the output list.

**The full code is below**:

```
function [mc_list,subcls_list] = q37829489(includeBulkFiles,includePackages)
%% Input handling
if nargin < 2 || isempty(includePackages)
  includePackages = false;
  mp_list = meta.package.empty;
end
if nargin < 1 || isempty(includeBulkFiles)
  includeBulkFiles = false;
  mb_list = meta.class.empty; %#ok
  % `mb_list` is always overwritten by the output of meta.class.getAllClasses; 
end
%% Output checking
if nargout < 2
  warning('Second output not assigned!');
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Get classes list from bulk files "laying around" the MATLAB path:
if includeBulkFiles
  % Obtain MATLAB path:
  p = strsplit(path,pathsep).';
  if ~ismember(pwd,p)
    p = [pwd;p];
  end
  nPaths = numel(p);
  s = what; s = repmat(s,nPaths+20,1); % Preallocation; +20 is to accomodate rare cases 
  s_pos = 1;                           %  where "what" returns a 2x1 struct.
  for ind1 = 1:nPaths  
    tmp = what(p{ind1});
    s(s_pos:s_pos+numel(tmp)-1) = tmp;
    s_pos = s_pos + numel(tmp);
  end
  s(s_pos:end) = []; % truncation of placeholder entries.
  clear p nPaths s_pos tmp
  %% Generate a list of classes:
  % from .m files:
  m_files = vertcat(s.m);
  % from .p files:
  p_files = vertcat(s.p);
  % get a list of potential class names:
  [~,name,~] = cellfun(@fileparts,[m_files;p_files],'uni',false);
  % get listed classes:
  listed_classes = s.classes;
  % combine all potential class lists into one:
  cls_list = vertcat(name,listed_classes);
  % test which ones are actually classes:
  isClass = cellfun(@(x)exist(x,'class')==8,cls_list); %"exist" method; takes long
  %[u,ia,ic] = unique(ext(isClass(1:numel(ext)))); %DEBUG:

  % for valid classes, get metaclasses from name; if a classdef contains errors,
  % will cause cellfun to print the reason using ErrorHandler.
  [~] = cellfun(@meta.class.fromName,cls_list(isClass),'uni',false,'ErrorHandler',...
     @(ex,in)meta.class.empty(0*fprintf(1,'The classdef for "%s" contains an error: %s\n'...
                                         , in, ex.message)));
  % The result of the last computation used to be assigned into mc_list, but this 
  % is no longer required as the same information (and more) is returned later
  % by calling "mb_list = meta.class.getAllClasses" since these classes are now cached.
  clear cls_list isClass ind1 listed_classes m_files p_files name s
end
%% Get class list from classes belonging to packages (takes long!):

if includePackages
  % Get a list of all package classes:
  mp_list = meta.package.getAllPackages; mp_list = vertcat(mp_list{:});  
  % see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.package.getallpackages.html

  % Recursively flatten package list:
  mp_list = flatten_package_list(mp_list);

  % Extract classes out of packages:
  mp_list = vertcat(mp_list.ClassList);
end
%% Combine lists:
% Get a list of all classes that are in memory:
mb_list = meta.class.getAllClasses; 
mc_list = union(vertcat(mb_list{:}), mp_list);
%% Map relations:
try
  [subcls_list,discovered_classes] = find_superclass_relations(mc_list);
  while ~isempty(discovered_classes)
    mc_list = union(mc_list, discovered_classes);
    [subcls_list,discovered_classes] = find_superclass_relations(mc_list);
  end
catch ex % Turns out this helps....
  disp(['Getting classes failed with error: ' ex.message ' Retrying...']);
  [mc_list,subcls_list] = q37829489;
end

end

function [subcls_list,discovered_classes] = find_superclass_relations(known_metaclasses)
%% Build hierarchy:
sup_list = {known_metaclasses.SuperclassList}.';
% Count how many superclasses each class has:
n_supers = cellfun(@numel,sup_list);
% Preallocate a Subclasses container: 
subcls_list = cell(numel(known_metaclasses),1); % should be meta.MetaData
% Iterate over all classes and 
% discovered_classes = meta.class.empty(1,0); % right type, but causes segfault
discovered_classes = meta.class.empty;
for depth = max(n_supers):-1:1
  % The function of this top-most loop was initially to build a hierarchy starting 
  % from the deepest leaves, but due to lack of ideas on "how to take it from here",
  % it only serves to save some processing by skipping classes with "no parents".
  tmp = known_metaclasses(n_supers == depth);
  for ind1 = 1:numel(tmp)
    % Fortunately, SuperclassList only shows *DIRECT* supeclasses. Se we
    % only need to find the superclasses in the known classees list and add
    % the current class to that list.
    curr_cls = tmp(ind1);
    % It's a shame bsxfun only works for numeric arrays, or else we would employ: 
    % bsxfun(@eq,mc_list,tmp(ind1).SuperclassList.');
    for ind2 = 1:numel(curr_cls.SuperclassList)
      pos = find(curr_cls.SuperclassList(ind2) == known_metaclasses,1);
      % Did we find the superclass in the known classes list?
      if isempty(pos)
        discovered_classes(end+1,1) = curr_cls.SuperclassList(ind2); %#ok<AGROW>
  %       disp([curr_cls.SuperclassList(ind2).Name ' is not a previously known class.']);
        continue
      end      
      subcls_list{pos} = [subcls_list{pos} curr_cls];
    end    
  end  
end
end

% The full flattened list for MATLAB R2016a contains about 20k classes.
function flattened_list = flatten_package_list(top_level_list)
  flattened_list = top_level_list;
  for ind1 = 1:numel(top_level_list)
    flattened_list = [flattened_list;flatten_package_list(top_level_list(ind1).PackageList)];
  end
end
```

The outputs of this function are 2 vectors, who in Java terms can be thought of as a `Map<meta.class, List<meta.class>>`:

- `mc_list` - an object vector of class [`meta.class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html), where each entry contains information about one specific class known to MATLAB. These are the "keys" of our `Map`.
- `subcls_list` - A (rather sparse) vector of cells, containing known **direct** subclasses of the classes appearing in the corresponding position of `mc_list`. These are the "values" of our `Map`, which are essentially `List<meta.class>`.

Once we have these two lists, it's only a matter of finding the position of your class-of-interest in `mc_list` and getting the list of its subclasses from `subcls_list`. If indirect subclasses are required, the same process is repeated for the subclasses too.

Alternatively, one can represent the hierarchy using e.g. a `logical` `sparse` adjacency matrix, `A`, where *a<sub>i,j</sub>==1* signifies that class `i` is a subclass of `j`. Then the transpose of this matrix can signify the opposite relation, that is, *a<sup>T</sup><sub>i,j</sub>==1* means `i` is a **super**class of `j`. Keeping these properties of the adjaceny matrix in mind allows very rapid searches and traversals of the hierarchy (avoiding the need for "expensive" comparisons of `meta.class` objects).

#### Several notes:

- For reasons unknown (caching?) the code may fail due to an error (e.g. `Invalid or deleted object.`), in that case re-running it helps. I have added a `try/catch` that does this automatically.
- There are 2 instances in the code where arrays are grown inside a loop. This is of course unwanted and should be avoided. The code was left like that due to a lack of better ideas.
- If the the "discovery" part of the algorithm cannot be avoided (by somehow finding all the classes in the first place), one can (and should) optimize it so that every iteration only operates on previously unknown classes.
- An interesting *unintended benefit* of running this code is that it scans all known `classdef`s and reports any errors in them - **this can be a useful tool to run every once in a while for anyone who works on MATLAB OOP** :)
- Thanks @Suever for some helpful pointers.

---

#### Comparison with Oleg's method:

To compare these results with Oleg's example, I will use the output of a run of the above script on my computer (containing ~20k classes; uploaded [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09232028226308829182) as a `.mat` file). We can then access the class map the following way:

```
hRoot = meta.class.fromName('sde');
subcls_list{mc_list==hRoot}

ans = 

  class with properties:

                     Name: 'sdeddo'
              Description: ''
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 0
              Enumeration: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 0
          InferiorClasses: {0x1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: [0x0 meta.package]
             PropertyList: [9x1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [18x1 meta.method]
                EventList: [0x1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0x1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [1x1 meta.class]

subcls_list{mc_list==subcls_list{mc_list==hRoot}} % simulate recursion

ans = 

  class with properties:

                     Name: 'sdeld'
              Description: ''
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 0
              Enumeration: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 0
          InferiorClasses: {0x1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: [0x0 meta.package]
             PropertyList: [9x1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [18x1 meta.method]
                EventList: [0x1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0x1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [1x1 meta.class]
```

Here we can see that the last output is only 1 class (`sdeld`), when we were expecting 3 of them (`sdeld`,`sdemrd`,`heston`) - this means that *some classes **are missing** from this list<sup>1</sup>*.

In contrast, if we check a common parent class such as `handle`, we see a completely different picture:

```
subcls_list{mc_list==meta.class.fromName('handle')}

ans = 

  1x4059 heterogeneous class (NETInterfaceCustomMetaClass, MetaClassWithPropertyType, MetaClass, ...) array with properties:

    Name
    Description
    DetailedDescription
    Hidden
    Sealed
    Abstract
    Enumeration
    ConstructOnLoad
    HandleCompatible
    InferiorClasses
    ContainingPackage
    PropertyList
    MethodList
    EventList
    EnumerationMemberList
    SuperclassList
```

To conclude this in several words: this method attempts to index **all** known classes on the MATLAB path. Building the class list/index takes several minutes, but this is a 1-time process that pays off later when the list is searched. It seems to miss some classes, but the found relations are not restricted to the same packages, paths etc. For this reason it inherently supports multiple inheritance.

---

<sup>*1 - **I currently have no idea what causes this.***</sup>

Comment: I would recommend using `pathsep` to split the output of `path` to you don't have any cross-platform issues. Nice solution though. Also in addition to all folders on the path, I'd look in `pwd` since that's technically on the path as well.

Comment: Does this work for classes which live inside of a package?

Comment: @Dev-iL: thanks for spending so much time on this question. Though your answer still has some limitations (interms of speed for instance) it is already a nice piece of code.

Comment: @Ratbert It is an interesting problem! Maybe all of us need to join forces (also @Suever), open a Github repository like Oleg suggested, combine all codes and make it into a nice and complete tool. ...and thanks for the bounty :)

Comment: Yes I agree, in the current form I can't run your code. I wanted to compare with my results.

Comment: @Oleg please explain. Do you get an error, or what? Feel free to come to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave) to discuss this.

Comment: No, I just don't get what I need to copy-paste, in which order and what to run first.

Comment: @Oleg Well just paste the first block and the second block into one file (`q37829489.m`) one after the other, make sure you assign both outputs, and disable `dbstop if error` if you have that on.

Comment: @Ratbert I'd like to point out that the long runtime is **only required once**, until the next time the classes visible to MATLAB change. After you ran the code for 2 minutes (or however long it takes on your system), you end up with two vectors of metaclasses, and processing them should be almost instant. You can then save those vectors somewhere (or the logical array I mentioned one can build from them) and just query _that_ result.

Comment: I just wanted to suggest that it is in your interest to give simple instructions and showcase how to use your solution.

Comment: @Oleg please see edited answer. I hope what I was doing is clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

### The code

I moved the code since it was > 200 lines onto the Github repository [getSubclasses](https://github.com/okomarov/getSubclasses). You are welcome to reqeut features and post bug reports.

### Idea

Given a **root** class name or a `meta.class` and a folder path, it will traverse down the folder structure and build a graph with all the subclasses derived from the root (at infinite depth). If the path is not supplied, then it will recurse down from the folder where the root class is located.

Note, that the solution is local, and that is why it is fast, and relies on the assumption that subclasses are nested under some subfolder of the chosen path.

### Example

List all subclasses of the `sde` class. You will need R2015b to be able to produce the graph, or you can use the output and the FEX submission [`plot_graph()`](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46070-plot-subfun/content/plot_graph.m) to produce a dependency graph.

`getSubclasses('sde','C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\finance\finsupport')`

[image]

And the output with the edges and node names:

```
 names      from    to
________    ____    __
'sde'        1      1 
'bm'         2      3 
'sdeld'      3      6 
'cev'        4      3 
'gbm'        5      4 
'sdeddo'     6      1 
'heston'     7      6 
'cir'        8      9 
'sdemrd'     9      6 
'hwv'       10      9
```

We can compare the result with the official documentation, which in this case lists the [SDE hierarchy](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/sde-class-hierarchy.html), i.e.

[image]

### Timing

On Win7 64b R2016a

- less than **0.1 seconds**: `getSubclasses('sde','C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\finance\finsupport')`
- about **13 seconds** if scanning the whole matlabroot: `getSubclasses('sde',matlabroot);`

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but, you could parse all `.m` files in the path as text, and use regular expressions to look for the subclass definitions.

Something like `^\s*classdef\s*(\w*)\s*<\s*superClassName\s*(%.*)?`

Note that this *will* fail silently on any subclass definitions that use anything fancy, such as `eval`.

Comment: It will also fail for `.p` files.

Comment: And it would need a more complex regex to match multiple inheritance.