# Programmatically return a list of all functions

Tags: matlab, function, namespaces, package, metadata

I want to programmatically get a list of available functions in the current MATLAB namespace, as well the available functions in a package. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe every function in MATLAB needs an associated .m, .mex, or .mex64 file in the path. You could go through each entry in `path()` and find all such files.

Comment: @jodag: that works. I'll accept if you put your comment as an answer.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37829489/3372061) might have some relevance to your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all built-in symbols in Matlab/Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840280/list-of-all-built-in-symbols-in-matlab-octave)

Comment: [My answer to that question ^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49843752/7328782) contains code that lists all known functions and methods, and shows how to do the same for a `+namespace` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use [package metadata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.package.getallpackages.html) for this:

```
pkgs = meta.package.getAllPackages();
% Or if the specific package name is known:
mp = meta.package.fromName('matlab')
```

The cell array returned in the 1<sup>st</sup> case, `pkgs`, contains objects such as this:

```
  package with properties:

                   Name: 'Sldv'
            Description: ''
    DetailedDescription: ''
              ClassList: [29×1 meta.class]
           FunctionList: [8×1 meta.method]
            PackageList: [9×1 meta.package]
      ContainingPackage: [0×0 meta.package]
```

So all that's left to do is iterate through the packages and sub-packages tand collect their `FunctionList` entries.

I'm not sure how to get the functions that belong to the "default" namespace, other than by parsing the [function list doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/functionlist-alpha.html), for example using the [Python API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html) and [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
fl = arrayfun(@(x)string(x{1}.string.char), py.bs4.BeautifulSoup( ...
       fileread(fullfile(docroot,'matlab','functionlist-alpha.html')), ...
       'html.parser').find_all("code")).';
```

Comment: Parsing that page is [pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51947138/3978545) :)

Answer (score 7):

Further to [Dev-iL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51946257/3978545), parsing the [function list documentation web page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/functionlist-alpha.html) is pretty easy because of the useful "function" class that the web devs have (currently) used to tag each function name with! Each function looks like this within the HTML:

```html
<code class="function">accumarray</code>
```

So we can use `urlread` to grab the source, and regular expressions to strip out the inner text of each `"function"` class item:

```matlab
str = urlread('https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/functionlist-alpha.html');
funcs = regexp( str, '(?<="function">)[0-9A-Za-z.]+', 'match' );
```

Note: "alpha" in the URL is for "alphabetical" rather than to denote early testing!

`funcs` is a cell array with all the function names on that page.

The page used above is for the most recent MATLAB version. For a specific version, use the historic documentation pages structured like so:

```
https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/matlab/functionlist.html
```

Comment: Neat answer, I would suggest however to use webread instead of urlread (it's deprecated), and you can remove the escape for the `.` in the character set.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness `webread` kept timing out (at 20secs) in my quick tests, whereas `urlread` was basically instantaneous.